# AWS Apigw v2 custom headers not being passed

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I've got an API gateway v2 which is using a proxy integration to lambda.

I'm trying to pass a custom header value via a GET call to my API.

```
...
                fetch(new Request(refreshUrl, {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: new Headers({
                        'refreshToken': user?.tokens.refreshToken
                    })
                }))
...
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get APIGW to pass that header value to my lambda.  When I log the event received in my lambda, my "refreshToken" header is nowhere to be seen.

I've tried to add parameter mapping such as the following to my lambda integration in apigw with no success:

```
$request.header.refreshtoken
```

And the documentation for such scenarios with AWS only seems to show for APIGW v1.

Comment: maybe this would help https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/custom-headers-api-gateway-lambda/

Comment: @GuneshShanbhag no that won't work.  If you try toset a transformation template (via aws api) for APIGW v2 then you get "Currently, transformation templates are not supported for APIs with a protocol type of HTTP". These docs are for v1.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

The issue wasn't related to APIGW.  The request parameter mapping is correct.

The problem was that I was proxying the api via cloud front and I needed to whitelist the header in my distribution.